# Not a pointer, Cannot dereference

Tags: c, pointers

Iam writing a code in C where structure is being passed by reference and is used in another function

Following is the called function declaration:

```
    float Compute(float input, struct constraints* limits_record, struct constraints* state_record);
```

Where limits_record and state_records both are structure declared as below:

```
    struct constraints
    {
       float lower_limit;
       float upper_limit;
    };
```

The above function is being called from another function(not from main) as follows:

```
    autotrim_out=Compute(inp, &limit, &state);
```

Following code details about the Compute function:

```
    float Compute(float input, struct constraints* limits_record, struct constraints* state_record)
     {
        float tmp_lim;
        float tmp_intgr;
        tmp_intgr =  coefficient * (input + state_record->lower_limit) + state_record->upper_limit;
        if (tmp_intgr < limits_record->lower_limit)
           tmp_lim = limits_record->lower_limit ;
        else if(tmp_intgr > limits_record->upper_limit)
           tmp_lim = limits_record->upper_limit;
        else
           tmp_lim = tmp_intgr;

       state_record->upper_limit = tmp_lim;
       state_record->lower_limit = input ;

      return(tmp_lim) ;
    }
```

On compiling the above code is giving error "Not a pointer, cannot deference" on the line

```
    tmp_intgr =  coefficient * (input + state_record->lower_limit) + state_record->upper_limit;
```

Can someone please help me regarding this...

Thanks in advance

Comment: As general advice for mysterious syntax errors: split up the line or expression into smaller pieces, until you understand the error.

Comment: The problem is in some code you haven't shown us.  I copy-and-pasted your code and compiled it on my system; once I added a declaration for `coefficient`, it compiled without error.  Show us a single complete self-contained source file that represents the problem.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with what you've posted - it looks OK to me, and it compiles fine under MSVC.  Take Lars Wirzenius - break the expression into smaller pieces, until you understand the error.

Comment: Thanks @KeithThompson and paulsm4
problem was with other part of the code

Answer (score 2):

Look for something in you code like:

```
#define coefficient
```

and change it to:

```
#define coefficient .42
```